# Inherit an :visited link with color of the link

Tags: css

Is there any quick way to make an `:visited` link the same color of the link itself?

For example:

```
* {color:black}
a:link {color:blue}
a:visited {color:inherit}
```

When I visit the link, this css turns the link on to black.
But I want to preserve the original color of the link (blue, in this case).

I think I can do something like:

```
a:link, a:visited {color:blue}
```

But, I have a huge css with many links, with different colors, and without comments from the stupid damned designer who coded this a year ago (me). Apply that solution will be a nightmare, because there are a hundred styles for links.

So... is there any way to **override `:visited` color with the "original" color**, without changing the whole stylesheet?

(This is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929618/set-visited-link-color-to-whatever-the-color-of-un-visited-link-is-p-s-not-the?rq=1), but none of the given answers works, and I can't use JS  (client requirements).)

Comment: if you put desired code at the bottom of your CSS it should override all previous styles.

Comment: Do you mean `:active` or `:visited`?

Comment: I mean "visited", sorry for the bad title and other `active` references....

Comment: @Elen Thanks, I know, but that's not what I want to know. I want to know if is there any quick way to override the `visited` style with the color of the original link.

Answer (score 0):

Until a better answer comes up, there is a partial solution: according to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Mozilla_Color_Preference_Extensions), Mozilla defines `-moz-visitedhyperlinktext` as the "visited" colour for hyperlinks.

So, if you have this HTML:

```html
<a href="#">This is what an a normally looks like</a>
<div class="test">
    <a href="#">This is an a in a black container</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <a href="#" style="color:-moz-visitedhyperlinktext">This is a visited a?</a>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```css
.test, .test * {color:black}
```

the `a` will come out looking "naturally", as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/NYgDD/1/). Only in Mozilla.

It won't work in other browsers, but you can write

```css
color:blue;
color:-moz-visitedhyperlinktext;
```

for the color, and other browsers will ignore the -moz- one.

Comment: Yes, especially if you don't also change the background colour to the default. Otherwise you might end up with the same fore- and background colours.

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly, but I get the impression that this solution does just the opposite to the expected result? I mean, I don't want a normal link displayed in "visited link" color, but a link "visited" displayed in "normal link" color... argh, what a mess :D

Comment: Hm, I should have put `-moz-hyperlinktext` instead of `-moz-visitedhyperlinktext`. But now but I see I totally misinterpreted your question. And I don't think there's an easy solution. `color:currentColor` doesn't work either. So, go through your stylesheets and change all `a:link` into `a` and remove all `a:visited`.

Comment: However, then the question comes up, why do you want to prevent your users from seeing which pages they have visited?

Comment: It's because client requirements: we must provide AAA accesibility and the "purple" color of visited links doesn't provide enough contrast with the background (for a few points, damn). So, I thought that if I could keep the default link color and show the visited link with a border, or something.... but as you say, it seems there's no easy solution for this :/